# Why does USR1 seem to kill Perl, instead of recreating the logfile?

Tags: perl, logging, log4perl

I have a Perl script that I've added logging to, courtesy of [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl/).

The script itself is long-running, and we also need to do log-rotation/archiving on a daily basis.

I've opted to use the inbuilt Solaris `logadm`, rather than using [Log::Dispatch::FileRotate](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aDispatch%3a%3aFileRotate), because

1. we're trying to reduce the number of Perl dependencies we need, and
2. I get the impression that doing it at the OS level, outside your app is the preferred/most robust approach.

As part of rotation, I also need to get the Perl script to refresh its file handle. According to the [Log4perl FAQ](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aFAQ#How_can_I_rotate_a_logfile_with_newsyslog?), you can configure it to listen for the USR1 signal, and recreate the file handles on that:

```
log4perl.rootLogger                                     = DEBUG, INFOLOG, DEBUGLOG

log4perl.appender.INFOLOG                               = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.filename                      = myprogram.info.log
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.mode                          = append
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.recreate                      = 1
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.recreate_check_signal         = USR1
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.layout                        = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.layout.ConversionPattern      = %d [%p] (%F line %L) %m%n
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.Threshold                     = INFO

log4perl.appender.DEBUGLOG                              = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.DEBUGLOG.filename                     = myprogram.debug.log
log4perl.appender.DEBUGLOG.mode                         = append
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.recreate                      = 1
log4perl.appender.INFOLOG.recreate_check_signal         = USR1
log4perl.appender.DEBUGLOG.layout                       = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.DEBUGLOG.layout.ConversionPattern     = %d [%p] (%F line %L) %m%n
```

However, for some reason, whenever I send the USR1 signal to the Perl process, my Perl script simply exits.

I'm sending it with:

```
kill -s USR1 <pid>
```

As soon as I do that, the Perl process seems to die. This happens whether I've configured Log4perl to capture USR1 or not.

I also tried using USR2, same effect.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here, either in Log4perl, or in Perl or Solaris?

Comment: Try to create a minimal test case that exhibits the problem. Perhaps your program is so big that it includes hidden side-effects such as [sigtrap](http://p3rl.org/sigtrap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second set of configuration for DEBUGLOG, you still have INFOLOG, but that shouldn't prevent the first from catching the signal. As suggested above, you may want to try a small example like below with your configuration:

```
# Your Log4perl config

Log::Log4perl::init( \$conf );

my $log = Log::Log4perl::get_logger("Foo::Bar");

while (1){
  $log->info("Important Info!");
  sleep 5;
}
```

If that works (did for me running on a Mac), then your system is sending the signals correctly and it's not Solaris. Then you can focus on what other code might be messing with the signal.